# SessionNotCreatedException at / Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

Tags: django, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, heroku

I am trying to deploy a app (selenium with geckodriver python3).

I am getting following trace back:

Traceback:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/app/mp3/views.py" in search
  20.                 driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=geckodriver)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py" in **init**
  167.                 keep_alive=True)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py" in **init**
  156.         self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py" in start_session
  251.         response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py" in execute
  320.             self.error_handler.check_response(response)

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py" in check_response
  242.         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

Exception Type: SessionNotCreatedException at /
Exception Value: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities